# Update PGF2.10 to 3.0 with tlmgr

Tags: texlive, installing

I want to update tikz pgf package from 2.10 version to 3. I tried hard but couldn't make tlmgr to update it. There seems some proxy issue with tlmgr.
I tried the solution provided here https://www.tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2008-September/017529.html. But it doesn't work either!

```
export http_proxy='http://sct2si1:xxxxxxxxx@10.4.102.12:8080'
export ftp_proxy='http://sct2si1:xxxxxxxxx@10.4.102.12:8080'
export TL_DOWNLOAD_ARGS='-c'
```

There are no issues with installing tlmgr and opening its gui. The only trouble comes when I try to update any latex package using it. Here is an error message, when I tried to update self. I tried using different mirrors etc.. nothing works.

```
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
TLDownload::get_file: response error: 400 You can not proxy through the ftp (for ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2013/tlnet-final/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb.xz)
TLUtils::download_file: persistent connection ok, but download failed: ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2013/tlnet-final/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb.xz
TLUtils::download_file: retrying with wget.
```

Can any noble soul out there help me solve this problem?

Comment: Can't you update at all or is there a difficulty just in regard to pgf? Can you download the package and install it manually? Give some more details...

Comment: tlmgr is not working at all on my system (Ubuntu 14.10). I solved the problem, anyway. I manually replaced the files in my system with the PGF3.0 .tex files. Its working file now.

Comment: OK, but "doesn't work" is not a helpful description. There may be many reasons. So edit your question and describe, how you installed tlmgr (did you succeed?) and what happens, if you, say, type `tlmgr gui` on the command line?

Comment: see the updated question...

Comment: if your "current" tex installation comes from the linux install, you need to get incremental tex stuff using `apt-get install`, rather than tlmgr.  i would have assumed that u14.10 would have the latest versions, but i don't currently use ubuntu-supplied tex, and since i've retired, i've no other machines to hand, to check.

Comment: There is only one version available in Ubuntu14.04 repository and that is 2.10. apt-get will not update it. Its tlmgr that updates the latex packages in linux. Anyways I am done with it. Thanks!